# Sitecore change rendering datasource

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Hello I would like create special page for private use for where i will be have possibility to change data source value for each rendering item.
I have created next code, but it dos't save any changes to items.

```
  SC.Data.Database master = SC.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
            SC.Data.Items.Item itm = master.GetItem(tbPath.Text);
            if (itm != null)
            {
                // Get the sublayout to update
                //string sublayout_name = txtSublayout.Text.Trim();
                //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sublayout_name))
                {
                    // Get the renderings on the item
                    RenderingReference[] refs = itm.Visualization.GetRenderings(SC.Context.Device, true);
                    if (refs.Any())
                    {
                        //var data = refs.Select(d=>d);
                        //refs[0].Settings.DataSource
                        var sb = new StringBuilder();
                        using (new SC.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
                        {
                            itm.Editing.BeginEdit();
                            foreach (var d in refs)
                            {
                                if (d.Settings.DataSource.Contains("/sitecore/content/Site Configuration/"))
                                {
                                    var newds = d.Settings.DataSource.Replace("/sitecore/content/Site Configuration/", "/sitecore/content/Site Configuration/" + tbLanguage.Text + "/");                                   
                                   // sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0} old: {1} new: {2}<br/>", d.Placeholder, d.Settings.DataSource, newds));
                                    d.Settings.DataSource = newds;
                                }
                            }
                            itm.Editing.EndEdit();
                        }                        
                        //lblResult.Text = sb.ToString();

                }
            }
        }
```

how I can change data source ?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing up two different things in Sitecore here.

- The datasource that is assigned to a rendering at run-time, when Sitecore is rendering a page
- The datasource that is assigned to the presentation details of an item

The simplest approach to achieve what I think you're trying to achieve, would be this.

```
Item itm = database.GetItem("your item");
string presentationXml = itm["__renderings"];
itm.Editing.BeginEdit();
presentationXml.Replace("what you're looking for", "what you want to replace it with");
itm.Editing.EndEdit();
```

(I've not compiled and run this code, but it should pretty much work as is)

Answer (score 1):

You are not saving the changes to the field.

Use the LayoutDefinitation class to parse the layout field, and foreach all the device definition, and rendering definitions.

And finaly commit the LayoutDifinition to the layout field.

```
SC.Data.Items.Item itm = master.GetItem(tbPath.Text);
var layoutField = itm.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField];


LayoutDefinition layout = LayoutDefinition.Parse(layoutField.Value);
for (int i = 0; i < layout.Devices.Count; i++)
{
    DeviceDefinition device = layout.Devices[i] as DeviceDefinition;
    for (int j = 0; j < device.Renderings.Count; j++)
    {
        RenderingDefinition rendering = device.Renderings[j] as RenderingDefinition;

        rendering.Datasource = rendering.DataSource.Replace("/sitecore/content/Site Configuration/",
            "/sitecore/content/Site Configuration/" + tbLanguage.Text + "/");
    }
}

itm.Editing.BeginEdit();
var xml =layout.ToXml()

layoutField.Value = xml;
itm.Editing.EndEdit();
```

The code is not testet, but are changed from something i have in production to replace datasources on a copy event

Answer (score 0):

If any one looking for single line Linq : (Tested)

```
var layoutField = item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField];
    if (layoutField != null)
    {
        var layout = LayoutDefinition.Parse(layoutField.Value);
        if (layout != null)
        {
            foreach (var rendering in layout.Devices.Cast<DeviceDefinition>()
                                     .SelectMany
                                     (device => device.Renderings.Cast<RenderingDefinition>()
                                     .Where
                                     (rendering => rendering.ItemID == "RenderingYoulooking")))
                                     {
                                         rendering.Datasource = "IDYouWantToInsert";
                                     }
            layoutField.Value = layout.ToXml();
        }
    }
```